# When should I use custom metric and when should I use event value?

Tags: google-analytics

There are two method to associate integer values to a google analytics event:

1. Sending a value along with the event, which I can see in the reports its sum and average values.
2. Setting custom metric value and then sending the event. Then I can create segments based on those metrics.

Given an integer value I want to associate with an event, when should I choose the first method and when should I choose the second? Are there use cases which fit to one but not to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event values will can be configured in goals to be added to your ecommerce revenue (if you do transaction tracking and have goals set up) so they will be included e.g. in ROI calculations for paid campaigns (so you can use it for optimization in adwords if your Google Analytics Account is linked to your Adwords Account) when a goal is counted.  That is AFAIK not possible with custom metrics at the moment.

(Of course that might be simply due to history, event values exist far longer than custom metrics in GA. In the end a custom metric is the generalized concept of a value applied to all interaction types.)

For custom metrics you can set various formats (time, currency with decimals,  integer) and min/max values whereas an event value is alway a positive integer with no (for practical purposes) upper limit.  So there are differences both in data collection and representation in the reports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it did add me some extra knowledge about what can I do with the data (adding to ecommerce revenue), I still didn't get the notion of when should I choose event value and when should I choose a custom metric. I've updated the question to reflect that more precisely: "Given an integer value I want to associate with an event, when should..."

Comment: Well for one custom metrics are a scarce ressource (you have only 20 of them and re-use is difficult at least), so with events you should probably always use event values (on the other hand you have only one value per event, so if you need multiple metrics connected with the event you would have to use custom metrics).